# RadioButton inside a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with a `TextView` that comprises a question and four `RadioButton`s for the answers. What is the best way of knowing if the `RadioButton` is the right answer? How can I count how many answers were correct ?

This is my `RecyclerView.Adapter` class:

```
public class QuestionarioAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <QuestionarioAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Questionario> questionarioList;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView perg;
    public RadioButton alt1, alt2, alt3,alt4;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        perg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvQuest);
        alt1 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.alt1);
        alt2 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.alt2);
        alt3 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.alt3);
        alt4 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.alt4);
    }
}


public QuestionarioAdapter(List<Questionario> questionarioList) {
    this.questionarioList = questionarioList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.questionario_perguntas, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Questionario questionario = questionarioList.get(position);
    holder.perg.setText(questionario.getQuestao());
    holder.alt1.setText(questionario.getAlt1());
    holder.alt2.setText(questionario.getAlt2());
    holder.alt3.setText(questionario.getAlt3());
    holder.alt4.setText(questionario.getAlt4());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return questionarioList.size();
}
}
```

This is my `List<>` class:

```
public class Questionario {
private String questao, alt1, alt2, alt3, alt4, altCerta;


public Questionario(String questao, String alt1, String alt2, String alt3, String alt4, String altCerta) {
    this.questao = questao;
    this.alt2 = alt2;
    this.alt1 = alt1;
    this.alt3 = alt3;
    this.alt4 = alt4;
    this.altCerta = altCerta;
}

public String getQuestao() {
    return questao;
}

public void setQuestao(String questao) {
    this.questao = questao;
}

public String getAlt1() {
    return alt1;
}

public void setAlt1(String alt1) {
    this.alt1 = alt1;
}

public String getAlt2() {
    return alt2;
}

public void setAlt2(String alt2) {
    this.alt2 = alt2;
}

public String getAlt3() {
    return alt3;
}

public void setAlt3(String alt3) {
    this.alt3 = alt3;
}

public String getAlt4() {
    return alt4;
}

public void setAlt4(String alt4) {
    this.alt4 = alt4;
}

public String getAltCerta() {
    return altCerta;
}

public void setAltCerta(String altCerta) {
    this.altCerta = altCerta;
}
}
```

This is the `MainClass` that is showing the questions:

```
  private List<Questionario> questionarioList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private QuestionarioAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_perguntas);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    mAdapter = new QuestionarioAdapter(questionarioList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new Divisor(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);




    prepareQuestionario();




    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_perguntas, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void prepareQuestionario() {
    Questionario questionario = new Questionario("Pergunta 1", "Alt 1","Alt 2","Alt 3","Alt 4", "1");
    questionarioList.add(questionario);

    questionario = new Questionario("Pergunta 2", "Alt 1","Alt 2","Alt 3","Alt 4", "2");
    questionarioList.add(questionario);

    questionario = new Questionario("Pergunta 3", "Alt 1","Alt 2","Alt 3","Alt 4", "3");
    questionarioList.add(questionario);

    questionario = new Questionario("Pergunta 4", "Alt 1","Alt 2","Alt 3","Alt 4", "1");
    questionarioList.add(questionario);

    questionario = new Questionario("Pergunta 5", "Alt 1","Alt 2","Alt 3","Alt 4", "2");
    questionarioList.add(questionario);

    questionario = new Questionario("Pergunta 6", "Alt 1","Alt 2","Alt 3","Alt 4", "3");
    questionarioList.add(questionario);

    questionario = new Questionario("Pergunta 7", "Alt 1","Alt 2","Alt 3","Alt 4", "4");
    questionarioList.add(questionario);

    questionario = new Questionario("Pergunta 8", "Alt 1","Alt 2","Alt 3","Alt 4", "2");
    questionarioList.add(questionario);

    questionario = new Questionario("Pergunta 9", "Alt 1","Alt 2","Alt 3","Alt 4", "2");
    questionarioList.add(questionario);

    questionario = new Questionario("Pergunta 10", "Alt 1","Alt 2","Alt 3","Alt 4", "2");
    questionarioList.add(questionario);

    questionario = new Questionario("Pergunta 11", "Alt 1","Alt 2","Alt 3","Alt 4", "1");
    questionarioList.add(questionario);

    questionario = new Questionario("Pergunta 12", "Alt 1","Alt 2","Alt 3","Alt 4", "2");
    questionarioList.add(questionario);

    questionario = new Questionario("Pergunta 13", "Alt 1","Alt 2","Alt 3","Alt 4", "4");
    questionarioList.add(questionario);

    questionario = new Questionario("Pergunta 14", "Alt 1","Alt 2","Alt 3","Alt 4", "3");
    questionarioList.add(questionario);

    questionario = new Questionario("Pergunta 15", "Alt 1","Alt 2","Alt 3","Alt 4", "3");
    questionarioList.add(questionario);

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}




}
```

I'll create a timer and get the answers. But how can I get the correct answer from the `RadioButton`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create these variables in your `RecyclerView.Adapter` class like so:

```
private int question = 1;
private int correct;
private int incorrect;
```

Create an `onClickListener` for each of your `RadioButton`s like this:

```
holder.alt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (question == 1) {
            // let's say this is correct
            question++;
            correct++;
        }  

        else if (question == 2) {
            // let's say this is incorrect
            question++;
            incorrect++;
        }  

        // ...    
    }
});
```

Make sure you write the code above for each of your `RadioButton`s and make sure each of your questions are used. See how you go.